# PHP self terminate for testing?

Tags: php

Currently I am using

```
$pid = getmypid();
exec("kill $pid");
exec("TSKILL $pid");
```

Is there a better, generic way?

Edit: `exit` runs destructors and shutdown functions. As the title suggests, I am testing and want to terminate immediately.

Comment: What is your testing trying to achieve?

Comment: @icecub How is that generic when http://php.net/manual/en/intro.posix.php says "This extension is not available on Windows platforms." I thought the `TSKILL` in the question showed the need for Windows, sorry for not elaborating.

Comment: @chx Right, my mistake. Sry man

Comment: @chx probably because it might not work on iis servers but don't know for sure as I have no experience with it

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to exit a PHP script without calling the destructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11302226/how-to-exit-a-php-script-without-calling-the-destructor)

Comment: Possible duplicate? Perhaps. Except I have a solution for that question, maybe not the most elegant but it certainly works. Should I move the question into an answer there?