# Why doesn't exit() prevent __destruct() from being called?

Tags: php, oop, destructor

I was wondering about the behavior of the magic method `__destruct()` and so I wrote a little test case that doesn't give me the outcome I would expect. Can someone clarify this for me?

I always thought that `exit()` would stop PHP from executing and in this case wouldn't be able to call `__destruct()`.

#### PHP Version

```
PHP 7.1.8-2+ubuntu14.04.1+deb.sury.org+4 (cli) (built: Aug  4 2017 14:30:23) ( NTS )
```

#### Code

```
class DestructorTest
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        print "Constructed\n";
    }

    public function doSomething()
    {
        print "Doing something\n";
        exit("Exiting...\n");
    }

    public function somethingElse()
    {
        print "Doing something else\n";
    }

    public function __destruct()
    {
        print "Destructing\n";
        $this->somethingElse();
        exit("Final exit\n");
    }
}

$destruct = new DestructorTest();
$destruct->doSomething();
```

#### Output

```
Constructed
Doing something
Exiting...
Destructing
Doing something else
Final exit
```

Comment: Because `exit` does not magically kill the PHP application.

Comment: For "The __destruct will not be called" you can see this [stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385047/when-will-destruct-not-be-called-in-php#answer-2385581)

Comment: [It's even in the manual](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php): `The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing. `

Comment: To keep this up to date ... as of php8 if exit() is called in the contructor then the destruct is not called on that object. This is because the object has not actually been created. This should be expected behaviour and fixes what was really a bug in previous versions. Destructors for objects already created WILL be called.