# PHP, in which circumstances the class destructor is not called

Tags: php, oop, destructor, php-7

I need to perform some important operations in the destructor,
so I want to know in which script termination scenarios the user-defined destructors are not called and I can't find it in the documentation.

Example:

- unhandled exception - called
- fatal error - not called
- interpreter receives SIGTERM - called
- interpreter receives SIGKILL - not called

etc...

Comment: Why do you need to run important operations in destructor instead of a regular code and do it when it is really needed and under your control? Especially in php when this is not a long running script and this is not about memory issue? Anyway here are some answers https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385047/when-will-destruct-not-be-called-in-php

Comment: @blahy because I need to run it on object destruction. It's important but it's not a problem if it doesn't get executed sometimes.
Thanks for pointing to the answer